# Include Start Date and the End Date in DateDiff function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm looking to get total number of days including the Start Date and End Date, some examples below:

```
Start Date  End Date     Tot#Days
08-04-2014  08-04-2014   1
08-04-2014  08-05-2014   2
08-04-2014  08-07-2014   4
```

I tried using the DATEDIFF function however I get a 0 for the first example, 1 for second example and 3 for the third which is not what I'm after.

Comment: what was the DateDiff function you used?

Comment: So use `DATEDIFF... + 1`?

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: I used DATEDIFF (DAY,STARTDATE,ENDDATE)

Comment: Yep, adding a '1' did the trick, can't believe how simple it was :) thank you and God bless you all

Comment: Yes, the datediff function just counts the number of date BOUNDARIES you must cross to get from one date value to the other.

Answer (score 4):

Just add 1:

```
select  datediff(day, [Start Date], [End Date]) + 1 as NumberOfDays
from    YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this in SQL SERVER:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, '8/4/2014', '8/5/2014') +1
```

You need to add **1** to the `DATEDIFF` function and it will work as you want.

Also to note that:

**[DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx)**

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

Answer (score 0):

I used

DATEDIFF('weekday',[StartDate],[EndDate])-2*(DATEPART('week', [EndDate]) -DATEPART('week', [StartDate]))

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked it just a tad to

```
IFNULL(STR(DATEDIFF('weekday',[StartDate],[EndDate]-2*(DATEPART('week', [EndDate]) -DATEPART('week', [StartDate])) +1)),'Active')
```